# "ld: library not found for -lreact-native-webrtc" while archiving product in ios xcode but works fine on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, webrtc

My app is working perfectly fine on simulator but while selecting generic device and doing archive I am getting error: ld: library not found for -lreact-native-webrtc. I am using React native 0.61.4 and xcode 11.4. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I've managed to deal with it by updating my pods IOS deployment target. It must be the same as for the project.
Maybe that will help you.
[XCode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN7RF.png)